# What is an Application Stack?

Tags: frameworks

I'm a self-taught software developer in nearly all of the languages that I know (though I'm properly learning Java now at school). I started in the desktop application universe but slid into the web application domain when it came to looking for work. Now, I'm constantly confronted with questions like:

- What stack are you using?
- What's your release strategy?
- Y U NO LIKE PHP?

Last one is a bit of a joke, I like PHP. But I'm not sure how to answer the first two. As far as I know, a **stack** would consist of the tools and software you use to present your application to the public. Things like Rails or Zend would be the MVC handling stack for web applications, and I assume that Qt or GTK+ would be a desktop application stack for MVC (if you build desktop applications like that, I'm used to the Window-Object-Service flow of things).

Comment: You're more or less correct about "stack": it's the libraries, frameworks, etc. that make your app go. A release strategy just means "how do you handle releases"? Continuous? If so, from where? Gradually-staged? Weekly? Quarterly? Etc.

Comment: It's as things are released and pushed. How does this work for desktop applications? Is there like a widely accepted definition for this?

Comment: It doesn't work any differently, it's just that with desktop apps, unless you force auto-update, not everyone will be running the same version--but that doesn't impact the release strategy itself.

Comment: Interesting, thanks @DaveNewton!